# How to implement an onScreen Keyboard in Android?

Tags: android

The default keyboard of android covers the EditText in my app UI. So i need to implement my on keyboard. Just like a keyboard in Regular Calculator app. Which is the best way to implement it? Is there any library available?

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic, and this is not a walk-through site. You are expected to show SOME effort (research/attempt). Right now, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom keyboard](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)

This link has everything required to create custom keyboard

Answer (score 0):

In order to do not hide your edittext under the keyboard, you need to add the following line inside your Manifest file, under your activity section.

```
 <activity 
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      ...
      ...
```

Moreover, depending on your needs you can have the numeric keypad or the common keyboard shown. But this is more than what you asked.